# SwiftUI detect top notch and safe area insets

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, uiwindow

I am looking for a pure SwiftUI based solution to determine whether the iOS device has top notch based on the safe area insets of the root view. While this is easy to determine in UIKit, for SwiftUI the only solution that I have found so far is also *UIKittish*, that is:

```
extension UIApplication {
     var currentWindow: UIWindow? {
       connectedScenes
         .compactMap {
             $0 as? UIWindowScene
         }
        .flatMap {
            $0.windows
         }
        .first {
            $0.isKeyWindow
        }
    }
 }

 private struct SafeAreaInsetsKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: EdgeInsets {
      UIApplication.shared.currentWindow?.safeAreaInsets.swiftUiInsets ?? EdgeInsets()
  }
 }
 
extension EnvironmentValues {
   var safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets {
      self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self]
   }
}

private extension UIEdgeInsets {
    var swiftUiInsets: EdgeInsets {
      EdgeInsets(top: top, leading: left, bottom: bottom, trailing: right)
   }
 }
```

While it's likely that SwiftUI will continue to use UIKit elements such as `UIWindow` under the hood so the solution above will continue to work for next several years, I still want to know if there is a pure SwiftUI based solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get safe area insets from a `GeometryReader`. You can put a `GeometryReader` at the very top of the view hierarchy, perhaps directly in `WindowGroup { ... }`. Then you can send the insets down with an environment key.

```
WindowGroup {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        // putting the text directly in a GeometryReader makes it align to the top left
        // which is why I am nesting it in a ZStack that covers the whole screen here
        // any other view that fills all the available space works too
        ZStack {
            ContentView() // the rest of the app is here 
                .environment(\.safeAreaInsets, geo.safeAreaInsets)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.safeAreaInsets) var insets
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(insets.top)")
    }
}

private struct SafeAreaInsetsKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: EdgeInsets = .init()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets {
        get { self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self] }
        set { self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to preview the whole `GeometryReader` for this to work in Xcode Previews. You can encapsulate the geometry reader and `ZStack` into a view modifier like this, so that you can conveniently use it in Previews:

```
extension View {
    func readSafeAreaInsets() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                self.environment(\.safeAreaInsets, geo.safeAreaInsets)
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView().readSafeAreaInsets()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. Just a question, can embedding `contentView` in `GeometryReader` have any side effects?

Comment: There is a problem with this answer. The unintended side effect is that now even subviews of `ContentView`, be it ZStack or VStack are placed at the top left.

Comment: Does not work, I will post minimally reproducible example shortly in the question.

Comment: Why did you use a preview of `ContentView`? You didn't give the `environment` to the preview, so of course the insets are 0. If you want to use previews, you should preview the whole `GeometryReader`, or manually give some insets using `environment`. Run the app and see for yourself. The code you posted works correctly when run on iOS 17 iPhone 15 Pro Max simulator.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Also I recommend deleting some of your previous comments. This comment section is getting long.

Comment: You are right, it works on the device but not in `Preview`. But if I use the UIKit based solution, it works in Preview as well! What is the difference?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Because there is no `GeometryReader` if you just did `#Preview { ContentView() }`. The UIKit solution works because it's UIKit. If you want a solution that also works with previews without adding an extra modifier like `readSafeAreaInsets`, I suggest asking a new question.